# Passing List<T> as query string

Tags: asp.net

I have a List having country names in the list. And this list needs to be sent as one of the parameters in Response.Redirect(page).

Is there a straight forward way to do this, so that in the recieving page, I can type cast the query string to List and use it.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you can do this. But if is a list comming from the database better call the function again on the revising page. Otherwise you have to do a dirty solution like this:

```
List<string> ls=new List<string>{"Sweden","USA"};
Response.Redirect("page.aspx?CountryList="+string.Join(",",ls));
```

And on the revising page do this:

```
List<string> ls= QueryString["CountryList"].Split(',').ToList();
```

But remember there is a limit on how large querystring you can send. So if the list contains many items then you can might reach that upper bound.

or store it in session:

```
Session["CountryList"]=ls;
```

And then on the revising page. Do this:

```
List<string> ls=(List<string>)Session["CountryList"];
Session.Remove("CountryList");
```

Remember to `remove` the `session` when you are done with it. So you do not have dirty values in the `session`

Answer (score 4):

Better using standard format... No ?

```
string queryString = "?country=" + string.Join("&country=", yourList);
```

Answer (score 1):

sending the string from List

```
 Response.Redirect("page.aspx?CountryList=" + string.Join(",", (string[])TargetArrayList.ToArray()));
```

getting the QueryString

```
string str = Request.QueryString["CountryList"];
    string[] arr = str.Split(',');
    TargetArrayList = arr.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how large your country list is.
 I generally use `Session["CountriesNames"] as List<string>` to pass such values between webpages in asp.net webforms.